# Error setting up S#arp Architecture 1.6 project from the Visual Studio 2010 project template in a 64bit O/S

Tags: visual-studio-2010, s#arp-architecture, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to get a brand new Sharp Architecture 1.6 project set up.  My environment is Windows 7 64bit, running Visual Studio 2010.  I have followed the instructions provided in the VS2010_ReadMe.txt.

In VS2010 I do File | New | Project, select S#arp Architecture Application, give it a name and hit 'OK'.  And I receive the following errors:

"A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'sharptest.Core'.  A project with that name is already opened in the solution."

"A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'sharptest.ApplicationServices'.  A project with that name is already opened in the solution."

... (it continues like this for each project)

I have not found any clear documentation regarding this issue.  I would appreciate help from someone who has successfully gotten a project based on the sharp architecture project template up and running successfully on a 64bit O/S running vs2010.  Thanks.

Comment: You'll have much better odds at the mailing list for the project: http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture

Comment: My membership is currently pending.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  However, my issue was resolved from creating the project in a different folder.  I receive the error when I try to create the solution in

> C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestProject

Changing this to

> C:\Code\TestProject

and I don't receive the error.

Do you have any subversion programs like AnkhSVN installed?  It would be worth uninstalling this and trying again.  Best advice I can offer.